# Extending "as x approaches a" to "as g(x) approaches a"

Tags: calculus, definition

All the definitions I can find of a limit (with functions from R to R) define something like:

"as x approaches a, f(x) approaches L"

Where x is treated as a variable that is quantified over in the definition.

Whereas many of these books then go on to use expressions of the form:

"as g(x) approaches a, f(x) approaches L"

without generalizing the definition appropriately.

Two questions:

1. what on earth makes this seem unproblematic to the authors?  I'm guessing that the way I view things makes this use of notation seem more problematic than it is.
2. What is the appropriate formal defintion of the limit of f(x) as g(x) approaches a, where f:S->R and S is a subset of R.

Comment: If $g$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $a$ then there are no problems here since $f$ is locally defined as a function of $g$. To be honest, though, I don't know any examples where it isn't already clear that $f$ can be written as a function of $g$; can you clarify?

Comment: Are you saying "lim f(x) as g(x)->a" is short for "lim f(g(x))   as x -> g^-1(a)"?  If so, why does g need to be invertible in a neighborhod, rather than just at the point?  (I mean, the second limit may not exist, but shouldn't that just tell us, then, that the first limit does not exist either?)

Answer (score 1):

The delta-epsilon definition of the limit generalizes in a straightforward way.  Suppose that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $|g(x)-a|<\delta(\epsilon) \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.  Then we say that $f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $g(x)$ approaches $a$.  Though it might be more appropriate to say "whenever $g(x)$ approaches $a$", since this could happen for more than one value of $x$.  For instance, $\sin(x)$ approaches $0$ whenever $\cos(x)$ approaches $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret the statement that f(x) approaches L as g(x) approaches a to mean that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all x, $0 < |g(x) - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Note that x need not be a real variable in order to apply this definition, though doubtless examples of that type come to mind.  For example, sin(x) tends to 0 as cos(x) approaches 1, but the converse is not true.

Comment: I'm not that surprised that someone gave the same answer as me, 12 seconds later, but the fact that you chose the exact same example is a little spooky :).

Comment: @mjqxxx: You were faster and had better LaTex!

Comment: Wait, why is the converse not true?

Comment: Oh, and what's the domain of the implicit universal quantifier over x--am I correct that, in the first case, we are saying 'for all x in the domain of f', and in the second case, 'for all x in the domains of both f and g'?  (Otherwise, a may be a limit point of domain(g) where every nbhd still contains points not in domain(g), which would make the limit undefined, even though it may be approaching a perfectly sensible limit--yes?)

Comment: @Quine42:  Nice nym.  The converse is not true because as sin(x) approaches 0, you get values of cos(x) near both &plusmn;1.  I do assume f,g have a common domain.  If not, then I agree an author owes you more of an explanation about what is meant by this phrase.

Comment: I take it back, shouldn't the implicit 'for all x' only need to be restricted to points in the domain of f?  If x is not in the domain of g, the antecedent of the conditional is false, so there will be no trivial counterexamples.

Comment: @Quine42: Well, I suppose you could employ a "vacuously true" interpretation in that case.  But I don't like it and would expect an author to be more forthcoming.  Consider a claim that as sin(x) tends to -2, cos(x) approaches 1.  It might be vacuously true but nonetheless deceptive if the author held a mental reservation that for sin(x) the domain is complex numbers while for cos(x) only real arguments are allowed.